# unable to call Salesforce api to external system shows cross origin error

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

hi all i am working in salesforce create one API,now i try to call that api into Angular project in http method as well but i am not able to get that it's shows error like this anyone help how to solve that problem.APi work fine POST MAN

Error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'false' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.salesforce
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to understand [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

And how to implement that using [salesforce REST services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm)